# Local fonts works locally but not on prod in NextJS 13

Tags: next.js, fonts, local, production

I have a problem with loading local fonts to my personal NextJS portfolio. The project itself is just a simple, static page.

It works fine locally but as soon as I've run `yarn run build` and upload it to my FTP server it shows a different font.

I've tried modifying a bit in my **next.config.js** file as well as double checking the path to the fonts but everything works locally. Its only on production I have this font problem. And when inspecting the font on prod it says the custom font I've set but its not displaying the correct one.

I don't get any errors in my console or see anything in the network tab.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  images: {
    domains: ['media.giphy.com', 'source.unsplash.com'],
    unoptimized: true
  },
  fonts: {
    unoptimized: true
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

and here's how I import the fonts in app/globals.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Fixture';
  font-style: 700;
  src: url('/static/fonts/Fixture-Ultra-Semibold.otf');
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Everett';
  font-style: 400;
  src: url('/static/fonts/TWKEverett-Regular.otf');
  font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Everett';
  font-style: 300;
  src: url('/static/fonts/TWKEverett-Light.otf');
  font-display: swap;
}
```

And using the local/ custom font looks like this

`h1 { font-family: 'Fixture'; }`

Tried modifying the next.config.js file and disable optimization for fonts since I had a similar problem with images before, which solved it the first time. But not for fonts.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as well. Also trying with next/font and still having problems. @oldskool123 were you able to solve?